# What is the purpose of app.py in django apps?

Tags: python, django, web

In Django 1.4 and above :

> There is a new file called `app.py` in every django application. It defines the scope of the app and some initials required when loaded.

Why don't they use `__init__.py` for the purpose? Any advantage over `__init__.py` approach? Can you link to some official documentation for the same?

Comment: `startproject` and `startapp` don't create `app.py`. Where have you seen it?

Comment: Django-oscar framework

Comment: `https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/tree/master/oscar`

Comment: Are you quoting `There is a new file called app.py in every django application. It defines the scope of the app and some initials required when loaded.` from somewhere ?

Comment: My bad.. I did `django 1.3` thought it must have been introduced with `1.4` when I saw `oscar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As all the links you have provided clearly show, this is nothing at all to do with Django itself, but a convention applied by the third-party app django-oscar.

Comment: Great! Just wanted to know if I am missing something.
Although, even if I was totally wrong I would have accepted "No" as an answer. Don't know why stackoverflow community downvote on genuine confusions. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Even though the details are wrong (there's no app.py in new Django projects), the question is still valid.

`__init__.py` is imported implicitly when importing a sub-module.  So if something in `__init__.py` executes automatically with side effects, you might run into unintended consequences.  Doing everything in `app.py` incurs a longer import, but separates package init from app init logic.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when people are learning a new technology they copy the file names as they saw on a tutorial. Some even continue using those either out of habit, out of thinking that is what they need to do, or they just like it. That might be why you see **app.py** so often.

Here is an example of one such tutorial https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-1-project-setup/

there they are building "flask by example" and the instructions give you this command

```
touch app.py .gitignore README.md requirements.txt
```

So of course now you have that file. This is the same for javascript projects where they might list **scripts.js** or css tutorials where they use **styles.css**.