# What is the use of apps.py, appconfig in django project. How and why to use it? could someone explain in a simple way

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, python-requests, web-development-server

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class App1Config(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app1'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of app.py in django apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533631/what-is-the-purpose-of-app-py-in-django-apps)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation,  but it happens that there's a previous question on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best explaination is already provided by Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications).

> To configure an application, create an apps.py module inside the
> application, then define a subclass of AppConfig there.
>
> When INSTALLED_APPS contains the dotted path to an application module,
> by default, if Django finds exactly one AppConfig subclass in the
> apps.py submodule, it uses that configuration for the application.
> This behavior may be disabled by setting AppConfig.default to False.
>
> If the apps.py module contains more than one AppConfig subclass,
> Django will look for a single one where AppConfig.default is True.
>
> If no AppConfig subclass is found, the base AppConfig class will be
> used.

Comment: So, if you have just one AppConfig subclass then is it true that the value of AppConfig.default is irrelevant?